# How do I write a time loop where I can execute different commands at different intervals over a 2 hour period

Tags: python, loops, time, intervals

My goal is to create a log grabber for troubleshooting purposes. The Python script would run for let's say 2 hours and do this.

1. Every 15 seconds run command 1.
2. Every 30 seconds run command 2.
3. Every 60 seconds run command 3.
4. Every hour run command 4.

I have used the basic time commands to do this individually, just wondering if I can combine it into a nested loop?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, using Python

Comment: I was able to get it working using the schedule module

Comment: Thx for adding information about your scripting language (it’s essential). When adding more information, please always do it in the question itself rather than as a comment. Also tag the question accordingly. Only this time I did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import schedule

def job1():
    print("job 1")
def job2():
    print("job 2")
def job3():
    print("job 3")

schedule.every(15).seconds.do(job1)
schedule.every(30).seconds.do(job2)
schedule.every(1).minute.do(job3)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why the final `time.sleep(1)`?

Comment: Hi Jack, I believe it's just to have it wait for 1 second before it checks if there are any pending jobs again. I checked the documentation on the module and it didn't give specifics on the time.sleep usage. I used their code example and modified it for my needs.